# Two different forms of the database connection string

Tags: postgresql, go

I have two different codes to connect postgresql with golang 
first code like this

```golang
connStr := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", user, password, dbName)
```

and the second one like this

```golang
connStr := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@localhost/%s?sslmode=disable", user, password, dbName)
```

What's the difference between them? And when do I have to use the second one?

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Connection_String_Parameters) to understand what these do. They are probably functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them work and as far as I know there is not real difference between them.

```
import "database/sql"

import _ "github.com/lib/pq"

connStr := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@localhost/%s?sslmode=disable", user, password, dbName)
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
```

///////////////////////////////

```
import "database/sql"

import _ "github.com/lib/pq"

connStr := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", user, password, dbName)
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

More info you can find here: https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq